# Is it possible to use https proxies with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to send requests, currently using the `requests` library, via an https proxy server. The issue is, as I understand it, urllib (the underlying request module) doesn't support it. Is there an alternative in python?

Comment: Read the friendly docs: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#id10

Comment: Perhaps I havne't explained my self clearly. The docs give you the example, but if you notice to the right, both of the proxies are http://. My issue is with the proxy itself being an https server

Comment: Have you tried `'https': 'https://<ip of proxy>'` ? True, the docs show an http protocol for https proxy, but I would not assume it's impossible to proxy through https -> https roundtrip

Comment: Yeah i tried, but unsuccessfully. Apparently yelling doesn't support it, so requests doesn't either